# Any solution for Cocoa push/pop of view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsviewcontroller

Let me get this out of the way: I'm used to to `UIKit`, where you can push/pop view controllers to your hearts content.  That just doesn't work on the Mac.

With [`TwUI`](https://github.com/twitter/twui), this works extremely well on the Mac. For example, look at `@joshaber`'s [push/pop example using TwUI](https://github.com/joshaber/TwUIPushPopTest).  If `TwUI` was completely stable and capable of embedding `AppKit` controls inside a `TUIView`, I would ditch AppKit completely.  However, not everything can be done in `TwUI`, and I need to retain AppKit for some things.

Thus brings my question.  How can something like this be accomplished using AppKit?  Is there a library that has made this easy?  Or do we need to make it ourselves?  Just using `replaceSubview:withSubview:` isn't enough, and isn't really pushing/popping views.

Comment: Push/pop of view controllers as in the example you linked to is not really "normal" Mac UI. It might work for a "wizard"-type interface on the Mac, but bear in mind that iPhones/iPads have a fixed screen size and all apps are full-screen, which is not the case on the Mac. What works for the mobile devices does not always transfer well to the desktop. That said, I can see that this would be beneficial for some UI components.

Comment: @Rob:  Excellent point, and normally I see how push/pop wouldn't be necessary.  However, for my app it's quite required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking about how to push/pop NSViews? I have another example on GitHub at https://github.com/joshaber/ReederDemo that does that. You can take the guts of PPNavigationController from TwUIPushPopTest and replace it with the stuff to do the animation in ReederDemo. It'd still be far from complete, but it'd at least get you pushing and popping view controllers with a kinda-right animation.

Comment: That's a start, but it's definitely not the push/pop I was thinking of.  Definitely is a step in the right direction, though.

Comment: In what way? The animation can obviously be customized depending on how much work you're willing to pour into it.

Comment: I guess it's just not like what I'm used to.  You're not actually "pushing" a view onto a stack, you're just transitioning between views.  I guess it's better than nothing but it's still not the real thing.

Comment: Are you saying I should transfer the actual push/pop guts from the `TwUI` example, or just the animation?

Comment: Right, take the actual push/pop guts from the TwUI example and the inspiration for how to do the animation from the ReederDemo.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I found what I was looking for.

Behold [**`PXNavigationBar`**](https://github.com/Perspx/PXNavigationBar):

[image]

Combining this and Josh's push/pop example I've come up with a good system.  I'll leave Josh's example selected because that fixes the root problem.